# What are the requirements for making a call on the Transponder snail (Den Den mushi) in One piece?

Tags: one-piece

The Den Den Mushi (DDM) is not much like a traditional telephone. It seems you don't need to know much about the other person's Snail (DDM) to make the call. And, It seems its signals can extend infinitely in any direction without much loss in Amplitude or quality.

**I mean how exactly does the snail know whom to connect**. And where they might be?
Are there hints about this?

Comment: [Wiki](https://onepiece.fandom.com/wiki/Den_Den_Mushi) claims that, while the telepathic ability of transponder snails is natural, when they "work as telephones", the snail that "makes the call" *usually* receives instructions on what snail to contact through an artificial, non-invasive device that works exactly like a normal telephone dial. If true (I can't really find the reference in manga or anime), then I suspect we can only assume that this works somehow.

Comment: Personally, I think that "where" people are might not be relevant to telepathy: the author could just decide that it works on pirate-snail magic and that it has nothing to do with real-world radiowave transmission.

Answer (score 1):

The Transponder Snails have the ability of telepathy. They know about the thoughts of each other. And there power of telepathy likely extends all over the world, so a person with a Transponder Snail can readily contact another person on the another side of the world.

Person 1 says something to the Snail 1. The Snail 1 sends the message via TELEPATHY to Snail 2. Snail 2 then interprets the message just like the voice of Person 1 and vice-versa